# Symlink to Volume

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina, I would like to create a symbolic link to my data partition using:

```
sudo ln -s /Volumes/data /data
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ln: /data: Read-only file system
```

(Whereas `/Volumes/data` is not read-only, and I can use it without any problems.)

Comment: In Catalina, `/` is read-only.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for you response. Does that mean there is simply no way how to do this? Even as sudo?

Comment: No, you *should* be able to do it with sudo, I just did it.  However, my error (without sudo) is "Permission denied", different than yours.  Could be just because I'm still back on High Sierra, but I don't think so.  My guess is that you have an existing folder at /data.  You can't symlink on top of an existing folder.  (I might be wrong about that, so let me say that if you CAN, you shouldn't.)  Try it with a different target folder.

Comment: @jimtut I think it is, as DanielB says, related to macOS Catalina. I have accomplished what I want on High Sierra. Also the folder surely does not exists, and I did also try with other names: the problem persists.